# Facing Video Playback Error (224003) on iPhones, despite Android compatibility. Need assistance

Tags: iphone, html5-video, jwplayer, mobile-browser

Our website features JWPlayer, which is responsible for playing our VOD (all the contents of the website). However, it has unexpectedly ceased functioning for the some random videos only for iPhone since. The android, and desktop version is all good, but for some unknown reason it is not playing on iPhone; showing error 224003.

We have confirmed that the files are fine, as we can play it successfully using on any android devices. Additionally, the mobile link is functioning without any issues on desktop.

Link to a reproduction page

https://www.parvizshahbazi.com/ganj_videos/mobile/singlevideo.php?id=ca284dc81&find=%D8%B4%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87%20%DB%B6%DB%B1%DB%B8&quality=high

We have contacted JWPlayer too but they mention the file is corrupted. Though as above mentioned, we can play it on android and desktop.

That said, we have also converted the files again with different encodings yet the issue is still ongoing.

Any advise?

Thanks in advance.